# Reducing time complexity in comparing contiguous subarrays?

Tags: python-3.x

So say I have a list sequences such as this.

I want to remove all sequences where its total sum = N and/or it has a contiguous subarray with sum = N.

For example, if N = 4, then (1,1,2) is not valid since its total is 4. (1,1,3) is also not valid since the (1,3) is also 4. (1,3,1) is also not valid for the same reason.

```
lst = [ 
    (1,1,1), (1,1,2), (1,1,3), 
    (1,2,1), (1,2,2), (1,2,3), 
    (1,3,1), (1,3,2), (1,3,3), 
    (2,1,1), (2,1,2), (2,1,3), 
    (2,2,1), (2,2,2), (2,2,3), 
    (2,3,1), (2,3,2), (2,3,3), 
    (3,1,1), (3,1,2), (3,1,3), 
    (3,2,1), (3,2,2), (3,2,3), 
    (3,3,1), (3,3,2), (3,3,3) 
]
```

E.g.

```
Input: 4 3
Output: 2 1 2
```

So what I have right now is

```
lst = [t for t in list(product(range(1,n),repeat=n-1)) if not any((sum(t[l:h+1]) % n == 0) for l, h in combinations(range(len(t)), 2))]
```

Currently it is in O(n<sup>2</sup>) if I'm not mistaken. What would be a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `numpy`, you can concatenate the total sum of each tuple with the contiguous value sums, then check if any of your resultign elements are equal to 4:

```
arr = np.array(lst)
arr[~(np.concatenate((np.sum(arr,axis=1).reshape(-1,1),
                      (arr[:,:-1]+ arr[:,1:])),axis=1) == 4).any(1)]
# or:
arr[(np.concatenate((np.sum(arr,axis=1).reshape(-1,1),
                      (arr[:,:-1]+ arr[:,1:])),axis=1) != 4).all(1)]
```

Returning:

```
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 1, 2],
       [2, 3, 2],
       [2, 3, 3],
       [3, 2, 1],
       [3, 2, 3],
       [3, 3, 2],
       [3, 3, 3]])
```